# How do I add a class to a row in a hook?

Tags: 8, views, hooks

I am building a view on my website that lists all currently pending user registrations. (They need to be approved by administrators). I also have a taxonomy that lists 'banned' names. The view lists the users username, email, discord name and twitch handle. I am trying to build a feature that takes any of those fields, and compares them to the 'banned' names list, and if a match is found on any or all of the fields, it adds a special class to the views row.

I can't find the appropriate hook to tie into that allows me to check these values, but also set a new style/class on the row if a match is found. I already have a function that takes the appropriate value and compares it to the taxonomy and returns a result, but I am not sure what hook to place this function in so that I can do if, for example:

`MatchFound()` goes through each provided value in the array, and if a match is found returns TRUE, or FALSE if not found at all.

```
$search = ['name','email','discord','twitch'];

if (MatchFound($search)) {
  'return flagged style for row'
}
```

Is there anybody that could help me?

Comment: Have you tried [template_preprocess_views_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_views_view/8.2.x)? A preprocess is typically where you'd add classes if you wanted to do it in PHP.

Comment: This hook appears to be at the individual field element level not at the query result level.